# Obtener valores al dar clic en el icono desplegable de un Datatable

Tags: vue.js, primefaces, vue3, primevue

estoy tratando de obtener el valor de la fila al dar clic en el icono para desplegar el detalle de esa misma fila.

Estoy utilizando Prime Vue, puedo desplegar la fila pero no puedo obtener el valor de esa fila.

Este es el código de mi datatable.

```
        <DataTable ref="td" :value="refproformas" v-model:expandedRows="proformas" dataKey="IDPROFORMAMANT"    
            responsiveLayout="scroll" :paginator="true" :rows="10" :filters="filters" class="p-datatable-gridlines"
                paginatorTemplate="FirstPageLink PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink LastPageLink CurrentPageReport RowsPerPageDropdown"
                :rowsPerPageOptions="[5, 10, 25]"
                currentPageReportTemplate="Vista {first} a {last} de {totalRecords} Documentos"
                expandedRowIcon="pi-eye"
                onRowClick
                >
                <template #header>
                    <div class="flex flex-column md:flex-row md:justify-content-between md:align-items-center">
                        <h5 class="m-0">Lista de Proformas </h5>
                        <span class="block mt-2 md:mt-0 p-input-icon-left">
                            <i class="pi pi-search" />
                            <InputText placeholder="Buscar" style="width: 100%" />
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </template>

                     <Column  headerStyle="width: 3rem" :expander="true" :onRowClick="listarmediocontacto()">
                 </Column>

                <Column field="fproforma" header="F.Proforma" :sortable="true">
                    <template #body="slotProps">
                        {{ fechaformateada(slotProps.data.F_PFR) }}
                    </template>
                </Column>
```

Donde **:expander= true** es para indicarle que se va expandir la fila, hasta ahi todo bien.
Pero no puedo obtener el valor de esa fila expandida, eh buscando pero el siguiente metodo
**:onRowClick** funcion pero como paso el **slotProps** para obtener el valor de mi fila seleccionada.

Alguna sugerencia ?